# Display Unity 4 UI above GUI?

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

Is there any chance to render Unity 4 UI (`Canvas`, etc.) that is set to `Screen Space - Overlay` above UI that is rendered via `OnGUI`/`GUI`?

I already have the UI `Canvas` Sort Order set to `Int16.max` (32767) and its placed on the UI layer. My script also makes sure that the Canvas is moved to be the last child. I think that's all that is possible to make sure that the UI in the `Canvas` is drawn top-most.

But there's some UI in a project that is drawn via the `GUI` class from the `OnGUI` method and it appears above my `Canvas` UI, no matter what. It would be great if this old way of drawing UI can somehow be tamed to move to the back. Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: Did you try [GUI.depth](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI-depth.html)?

Comment: Yes I did but it doesn't change anything, GUI still stays topmost even if I set GUI.depth to -100 or -1000.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible (so far I know and tested). If you refer to Unitys execution order documentation http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html you can see that `OnGUI` renders after everything else. Resulting in that `OnGUI` will always render on top.